# Select values that begin with a number

Tags: sql, mysql, select, numbers

I have a table with a column containing data that begin with numbers too, on MySQL

How can I select the rows that begin only with a number?

Comment: Same general sentiment as this thread on how to [Detect if value is number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5064977/1366033), but just restricted to the first char

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn regexp '^[0-9]+'
```

Comment: +1 for `REGEXP` (I don't think `LIKE` supports RegEx (as @RedFilter) has implied). Though, I would probably use `'^[0-9]+'` as a pattern myself.

Comment: Do I need to add any assembly or something to use REGEXP in MS SQL server?

Comment: Hey can you post the sqlite version for the query above because regexp in  not available in some android devices. Thanks in advance

Comment: you may also use rlike instead of like

Comment: whyn not `'^[0-9].+'`?

Answer (score 13):

Yet another way:

```
WHERE LEFT(columnName,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

and with common charsets and collations, this would work and use an index on the column:

```
WHERE columnName >= '0' AND columnName < ':'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn REGEXP '^[0-9]';
```

The regular expression used is `^[0-9]`.

```
^    - Start anchor, used to ensure the pattern matches start of the string.
[    - Start of character class.
0-9  - Any digit
]    - End of character class
```

Effectively we are trying to select those values in the column that ***begin with a digit***.

Demo:

```
mysql> select * from tab;
+-------+
| col   |
+-------+
| 1foo  |
| foo   |
| 10foo |
| foo10 |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tab where col regexp '^[0-9]';
+-------+
| col   |
+-------+
| 1foo  |
| 10foo |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 6):

also

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE '[0-9]%';
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`artists\` WHERE \`artist\` LIKE '[0-9]%'` returns empty.

Comment: MySQL's `like` does not support such patterns. You have to use `regexp` for that. e.g.: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP '^[0-9]'`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.COLUMNNAME REGEXP '^[0-9]';
```

Another answer is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.COLUMNNAME RLIKE '^[0-9]';
```

Comment: "`RLIKE is a synonym for REGEXP`"