# Detect if value is number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Is there a way to detect if a value is a number in a MySQL query? Such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE isANumber(col1) = true
```

Comment: I have tested the 1*col = col strategy, but somehow it fails when the query is called via PHP (returning true when it shouldn´t). In phpMyAdmin however, the hack works. This means my test behaves as expected, buy my application doesn´t.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

This should work in most cases.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE concat('',col1 * 1) = col1
```

It doesn't work for non-standard numbers like

- `1e4`
- `1.2e5`
- `123.`  (trailing decimal)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I need it to recognise that 123 is a number, but 123X is not.

Comment: @Richard- I just read the exceptions you gave. Thought you meant the character "e". I see what you mean now.

Comment: Leading zeros are not an issue for a deft sql developer --- trim(leading 0 from col1)

Comment: I know it's an old post but I use this method in my query. But I've a problem, it detects "2-Power" as "2" causing trouble as it's not supposed to do that. 
Any idea ?

Comment: @GaspardRosay What do you mean it detects? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8315/2  shows that "2-Power" is **not** detected as a number, as intended.

Comment: For trailing and leading zeros (ex. 023.12000) :
concat('', col1 * 1) = '0' OR concat('', col1 * 1) = IF(LOCATE('.', col1), TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM col1), TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM col1));

Comment: CONCAT('', col1 * 1) is not necessary. CONCAT(col1 * 1) works as well. You don't have to pass 2 agruments to concat() function.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate with an empty string. `concat(col1 * 1) = col1` is the same (at least in newer versions). `concat(x)` works like casting to string.

Comment: i know its an old post, but since it still ranks high on google i got here. the method in this answer actually fails on mariadb UPDATE queries, and i suggest using the proposed REGEXP in other answers

Comment: @yoadw can you be more specific? What does it fail on in your UPDATE query?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi i am getting "Error 1292: truncated incorrent DOUBLE value: <value> '. it may be something specific with my db values. don't remember my research results from back then, but i gave up and used the regex approach.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi this will output the error
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'x'
for non convertable string, which can and will be ignored by almost everyone, but I explicitly googled this question to avoid getting this error.

Answer (score 414):

You can use Regular Expression too... it would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

**Reference:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';

Comment: The accepted answer is really clever, but this answer is more direct, and I think it should be the accepted solution.

Comment: For the case of "doesn't match": `WHERE col1 NOT REGEXP...`, and for the case where you might have a decimal point, use regex: `^[0-9\.]+$`

Comment: @DmitriyKozmenko If "number" includes decimals, then the regexp is no longer "more direct" and a solution is not offerred in comments or the answer.

Comment: Also won't work for scientific notation, only works for ints

Comment: Regex migth be hard to read for people that never used it, but you can do really great and short things with it

Comment: also instead of NOT you can use regexp `[^0-9]+$` which means not in set of 0-9 symbols

Comment: It'd be grand if MySQL supported a `ISNUMERIC()` function!

Answer (score 76):

If your data is 'test', 'test0', 'test1111', '111test', '111'

To select all records where the data is a simple int:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Result: '111'

(In regex, ^ means begin, and $ means end)

To select all records where an integer or decimal number exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$'; - for 123.12
```

Result: '111' (same as last example)

**Finally,** to select all records where number exists, use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE col1 REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Result: 'test0' and 'test1111' and '111test' and '111'

Comment: I like this approach better because it's clearer and less "hackish" than the concatenation trick. Thanks!

Comment: Not working for negative values. I'd amend the proposed regexp as follows : `REGEXP '^[+\-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$'`

Comment: I'd say the "+" symbol is not necessary, you could use just a "-?", but if you want to use it, you should escape it (and the "-" symbol doesn't need to be escaped).

Comment: The `+` would be required if you're matching data like `+12.34`. There's an argument that the data should be validated before insert, but we're talking about a situation where a float has been stored as a string, so things aren't always ideal.

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[+-]?[0-9]*([0-9]\\.|[0-9]|\\.[0-9])[0-9]*(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?$'
```

Will also match signed decimals (like *-1.2, +0.2, 6., 2e9, 1.2e-10*).

Test:

```
drop table if exists myTable;
create table myTable (col1 varchar(50));
insert into myTable (col1) 
  values ('00.00'),('+1'),('.123'),('-.23e4'),('12.e-5'),('3.5e+6'),('a'),('e6'),('+e0');

select 
  col1,
  col1 + 0 as casted,
  col1 REGEXP '^[+-]?[0-9]*([0-9]\\.|[0-9]|\\.[0-9])[0-9]*(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?$' as isNumeric
from myTable;
```

Result:

```
col1   |  casted | isNumeric
-------|---------|----------
00.00  |       0 |         1
+1     |       1 |         1
.123   |   0.123 |         1
-.23e4 |   -2300 |         1
12.e-5 | 0.00012 |         1
3.5e+6 | 3500000 |         1
a      |       0 |         0
e6     |       0 |         0
+e0    |       0 |         0
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifGcAyNJx2qu9AGgxPmLHf/0)

Comment: Fails for '1s' or '1x'.

Comment: @stef - What exactly fails there? The query tells me that '1s' and '1x' are not numeric. Is that wrong? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vBJqhaqweSaCVTfBnjxnaM/0

Answer (score 14):

**Returns numeric rows**

I found the solution with following query and works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 > 0;
```

This query return rows having only greater than zero number column that `col1`

**Returns non numeric rows**

if you want to check column not numeric try this one with the trick (`!col1 > 0`):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE !col1 > 0;
```

Comment: This does not work, if you have a string that starts with a number "123abc" it will be returned in your numeric rows statement and not in the non-numeric statement.

Comment: @JStephen You right! Because `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 123;` query will return rows even col value is `123abc`

Answer (score 9):

This answer is similar to Dmitry, but it will allow for decimals as well as positive and negative numbers.

```
select * from table where col1 REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$'
```

Answer (score 9):

use a UDF (user defined function).

```
CREATE FUNCTION isnumber(inputValue VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    IF (inputValue REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$'))
    THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Then when you query

```
select isnumber('383XXXX')
```

--returns 0

```
select isnumber('38333434')
```

--returns 1

select isnumber(mycol) mycol1, col2, colx from tablex;
-- will return 1s and 0s for column mycol1

--you can enhance the function to take decimals, scientific notation , etc...

The advantage of using a UDF is that you can use it on the left or right side of your "where clause" comparison. this greatly simplifies your SQL before being sent to the database:

```
 SELECT * from tablex where isnumber(columnX) = isnumber('UnkownUserInput');
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative that seems faster than REGEXP on my computer is

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1*0 != col1;
```

This will select all rows where col1 starts with a numeric value.

Comment: What about if the value is zero?

Comment: I guess you could just add `AND col1<>0` to handle that exception.

Comment: It is true that it doesn't work for zero values but it perfectly works for padded numbers, e.g. 004. The accepted answer does not work for padded numbers

Comment: I think this is the best way to check for numbers. It's just that we need to add an OR statement for checking zero, as

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1*0 != col1 OR col1='0';

Comment: I get a false positive for `'1a'`. BTW: it's equivalent to `WHERE col1 <> 0` - http://rextester.com/DJIS1493

Answer (score 4):

Still missing this simple version:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `col1` + 0 = `col1`
```

(addition should be faster as multiplication)

Or slowest version for further playing:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN `col1` + 0 = `col1` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `IS_NUMERIC` 
FROM `myTable`
HAVING `IS_NUMERIC` = 1
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, MySQL converts any string to a 0 so this will not distinguish between strings and numbers, both will return the same.

Comment: `'a' + 0 = 'a'` is TRUE

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression for the mor detail https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

I used this `^([,|.]?[0-9])+$`. This is allows handle to the decimal and float number

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    myTextField REGEXP "^([,|.]?[0-9])+$"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about how this solves the question

Answer (score 1):

I recommend: if your search is simple , you can use `

```
column*1 = column
```

` operator interesting :) is work and faster than on fields varchar/char

> SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column*1 = column;

```
ABC*1 => 0 (NOT EQU **ABC**)
AB15*A => 15 (NOT EQU **AB15**)
15AB => 15 (NOT EQU **15AB**)
15 => 15 (EQUALS TRUE **15**)
```

Comment: Are you aware that in MySQL both the `select 'aaa123' >= 0` and  `select '123aaa' >= 0` return true?

Comment: @ Grzegorz Smulko  is not right. SELECT 'aaa123'*1 returns to 0 it is not equal to self and

SELECT '123aaa'*1 returns to 123 it is not equal to self

Comment: this is a problem `SELECT '123abc' * 1 = '123abc'`  will convert both sides to numbers and be TRUE because 123 = 123. We need to make sure the comparison is done as a STRING.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE sign (col1)!=0
```

ofcourse sign(0) is zero, but then you could restrict you query to...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE sign (col1)!=0 or col1=0
```

> UPDATE: This is not 100% reliable, because "1abc" would return sign of
>   1, but "ab1c" would return zero... so this could only work for text that does not begins with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do using `CAST`

```
  SELECT * from tbl where col1 = concat(cast(col1 as decimal), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works quite well

```
if(col1/col1= 1,'number',col1) AS myInfo
```

Comment: It's the same as to check for `col1 <> 0` and gives a false positive for `1a` - http://rextester.com/HLORBZ1242

Answer (score -1):

Try Dividing /1

```
select if(value/1>0 or value=0,'its a number', 'its not a number') from table
```