# sql expression pattern matching

Tags: sql, case, teradata, sql-like

I want to check for a pattern in sql such that if there is anything in that expression (or table cell) other than numeric it should return 1. If that whole cell has only numeric values it should return 0

eq:

```
case when '200290' like [anything other than numbers]
then 1
else o
```

Comment: What DB are you using? SqlServer? Could you use [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)?

Comment: I am trying not to use any sql functions. The data base is teradata but a query in SQL server is also good

Comment: Sorry, -1 to me for not seeing tags.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql for a mysql answer

Comment: @Widor - `Isnumeric` is a notoriously buggy function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use something like (I'm not writing the whole function for  you):

```
DECLARE @t varchar(100) = '231321321321'

SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @t) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: @user708477 It's a common problem and a common solution.  `ISNUMERIC()` doesn't work as expected so we have to come up with workarounds!

Comment: As of Teradata 13.10, you would need to replicate PATINDEX() functionality as a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE CHARACTERS(OTRANSLATE(<your_string>,'a1234567890','a')) 
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Ex.:

```
     -- BTEQ  Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
SELECT CASE CHARACTERS(OTRANSLATE('12345','a1234567890','a')) 
WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

*** Query completed. One row found. One column returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

```
<CASE  expression>
------------------
                 0

SELECT CASE CHARACTERS(OTRANSLATE('1a23b45c','a1234567890','a')) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

*** Query completed. One row found. One column returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

```
<CASE  expression>
------------------
                 1
```