# Checking for character existence in a field

Tags: mysql

I want to select from my number table that haven't any character except + in index.
For example:

- +991234567 is ok
- 98+4587889 is not ok
- 14asdasda54866666 is not ok

How should i write my query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if value is number in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is your end outcome, are you simply checking for invalid numbers?

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions on MySQL to do so http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: @Lloyd i think he tries to check for valid phone numbers and internationals start with + ;o) but he should have mentioned it in question

Comment: @SirRufo yeah sry if my question not completly clear

Comment: So check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql can probably just add a NOT somewhere.

Comment: but also your comments are misleading. @Lloyd asked if you are looking for invalid numbers. But +99.. is an invalid number. But it is not an invalid phone number. so you better be more precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Query with the Regular Expression

```
SELECT 
  number
FROM 
  Table1
WHERE 
  number NOT REGEXP '^\\+{0,1}(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*$'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66f92/1/0)