# Checking rows that are not numbers in a varchar column for MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

In a perfect world for this type of setup, we would have an integer column that expects only numbers;

But what if you have a `varchar` column and you want to add a `WHERE` clause that said something like this:

`WHERE <value> is NOT a number`

In essence, you are selecting all rows that contain any characters that are NOT ONLY numbers.

This is for MySQL.

Comment: This should answer your question [Detect if value is number in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5065007/560299)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE concat('',col1 * 1) != col1
```

[demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2984dc/1)

Comment: It SEEMS regular expressions made more sense but we decided to go this route.  It's simple, and returns what we need.

Answer (score 3):

[`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) are your friends:

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `Column` RLIKE '^[^0-9]*$';
```

---

**UPDv1:**

You may use different regexes to detect negative integers:

```
SELECT
'-2' RLIKE '^[^0-9]*$', -- fails
'-1' RLIKE '-[0-9]';    -- succeeds
```

*For example:*

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `Column` RLIKE '-[0-9]' OR `Column` RLIKE '^[^0-9]*$';
```

---

Tested with this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 'abs 12 x' as `Column`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 12
        UNION ALL
        SELECT -2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '-x'
    ) as `sub`
WHERE
    `Column` RLIKE '-[0-9]'
    OR
    `Column` RLIKE '^[^0-9]*$';
```

Output:

```
-2
-x
```

Comment: How would you do this to allow Negative values such as "-2" be allowed?

Comment: @KickingLettuce You need to allow negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This would approach somehow your goal:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NOT MyTable.Field1 REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]*$';
```

As Field1 is VARCHAR, this will select all rows that Field1 is not wholly numerical.

If you have floating-point value:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE NOT MyTable.Field1 REGEXP '^[[:digit:]\.]*$';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a regular expression in the where clause.
The following mysql documentation link provides details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html