# query="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE `VarCharCol1`= numeric"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with varchar column, this column contains both numeric records and AlphaNumeric records, but require only the ones that have no letters.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense? Can you clarify your question please.

Comment: Its usually pretty bad practice to do this, you should really ensure that if you want something in a particular format you set the column with this type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if value is number in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `varcharcol1` RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: This should do the job after fixing it.

Comment: @ВикторПеров oops sorry, thanks for the pointer

Comment: Both REGEXP and RLIKE seem to work. What is the difference?

Comment: RLIKE is a synonym for REGEXP. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 2):

tryed

```
SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(column_name) = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work:
FUNCTION ISNUMERIC does not exist

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where concat('', column * 1) = column;
```

Returns array of data, where column is numeric (contains only digits).

Comment: WOW, this is an interesting one, strange, but logical. And it actually works!