# MySQL - Select only numeric values from varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql, numeric, varchar

Consider the following table :

```
create table mixedvalues (value varchar(50));

insert into mixedvalues values 
('100'),
('ABC100'),
('200'),
('ABC200'),
('300'),
('ABC300'),
('400'),
('ABC400'),
('500'),
('ABC500');
```

How can I write a select statement that would only return the **numeric** values like

```
100
200
300
400
500
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d894/1)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: `^-?[0-9]+$' don't forget possible negative numbers.

Comment: Does it work if the column stores data like: abc mnop prqs xyz 71.6789 30.7654 ?

Comment: @Nisha No. This is a different question

Comment: how do we enhance it to work for decimal values as well?

Comment: @Aqua4 I think that is a question in itself

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE concat('',value * 1) = value;
```

Reference:  [Detect if value is number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Comment: This solution works for the moment, but gives you a `Warning: #1292`

Answer (score 4):

You were close :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE value > 0;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d894/2)

Comment: This is much simpler than the other answer. How does it work?

Comment: This relies on the fact that the letters never appear after the numbers

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I noticed it will fail for something like 600ABC.

Comment: This isn't a suitable and could create issues later.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.
'1ABCABC' will be returned using this query which is clearly NOT a numeric value.

Comment: Not only that, but all those non-convertible values will cause warnings. That's not a problem unless you're running in strict-mode....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE value > 0 
ORDER BY CAST(value as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

List item has string continue with numbers

```
$string = "Test";

select * from table where columnname REGEXP "$string-*[0-9]+";
```

Comment: if you wanna search for numbers with certain decimals: ([0-9]){2,3} to match numbers from 10..999

Answer (score -4):

You can filter your result set using the `ISNUMERIC` function:

```
SELECT value
FROM #mixedvalues 
where ISNUMERIC(value)=1
```

Comment: Question was for mysql.

Comment: This function does not exist in MYSQL.