# how to check value is numeric or not a numeric in mysql select query as follow

Tags: mysql

value->{1,2,Yes,No,5,6}

```
select if((value is numeric),value,'not a numeric') as column_name
```

how to implement this if in my mysql select query

Comment: Duplicate question with other great answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql

Although it was not the accepted answer on that question, the best answer might be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48789594/564664

Answer (score 6):

This should do it :)

```
select if(field REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' > 0, field, 'not a numeric') as column_name
```

Example:

```
SELECT '12345' REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

Returns: 1 (its a number)

```
SELECT 'abcdef' REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

Returns: 0 (its NOT a number)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but when I needed the same thing the fastest solution was

```
select if((value *1),value, 'not a number') as column_name;
```

Granted, this will not consider zero a number, but neither did the Romans and they did ok for thousands of years. For me, given the improved speed across the hundreds of millions of rows, this was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it-

```
SELECT IF(table_column*1>0,table_column,'Not a Numeric') 
FROM your_table;
```

Note: If there is a value "9 hello" then it will be treat as numeric as 9 is numeric value, if you need to exclude it also then revert. But in your question there is no such value.