# Should querying for empty string match zero on a primary key column?

Tags: mysql, select

I have this mysql query that has made me totally stumped all day:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = "";
```

I am surprised that this query returns a row where id is "0". Is this the expected behaviour? And if yes, how should I go about excluding this row? I need this query to return no rows when I pass the empty string.

Now `id` is a primary key column and `auto_increment`, if that's may help.

**EDIT**

It gets even more interesting. I have just run the query with an arbitrary string, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = "xyz";
```

It still returns the row with the id of zero. It looks like the query is somehow casting my query parameter to INTEGER. This is new to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you query is that `""` or `"xyz"` is *implicitly* converted to `0`. Try this to see for yourself:

```
SELECT CAST("" AS SIGNED), CAST("xyz" AS SIGNED)
```

You can also have a look at the [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) to better understand implicit type conversion.

I would suggested checking the value of your parameter *before* issuing the query. If the user has given a non-numeric value as input then inform him/her accordingly.

In MySQL you can use a method suggested in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql) post to check if the parameter value is numeric:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE id = "" AND (CONCAT('', @param * 1) = @param);
```

where @param = "" or "xyz" or "123".

Comment: Yep. I guess "implicit type conversion" is what's going on. I was interesting when I was just reminded that `SELECT "xyz" = 0;` yields `TRUE`.So, I think the problem was created by a combination of this, and the  (unusual) presence of a "0" value on that INTEGER column.

Answer (score 0):

It will return `false`

```
IF('', 'true', 'false')
```

or 
It will return `false`

```
IF('', 'true', 'false')
```

> For MySQL meaning `zero` or `''` indicates false

[Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

The "unexpected" behaviour is indeed the expected one, considering *implicit type conversion* as pointed out by @Giorgos. Deferring to that then, I believe the most straightforward means of achieving what I want in this query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(`id` AS CHAR)="";
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(`id` AS CHAR)="xyz";
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(`id` AS CHAR)="123";
```

This way, both sides of the argument are STRING, and apples are compared with apples.

That being said, I'm going to accept @Giogos's answer. It does point to the solution.