# How to exclude non-numeric column results from MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column, called `value`, that includes strings as well as numbers as data, eg:

- **contentid**, **value**
- 16, 200
- 18, 150
- 47, Foo
- 16, Red
- 16, 50
- 18, GREEN

I need a way to retrieve only the results that are actual numbers (and, additionally, that are `<= 180`).

The expected results from above should be: `18, 150` and `16, 50` but I am getting results with strings as well.

I have tried this from other SO questions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `contentvalues` 
WHERE (
contentid =16
OR contentid =18
)
AND `value` <= 180
AND value NOT LIKE  '%[a-z0-9]%'
```

But this has not worked.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ash.burton.fm/blogs/2010/12/quick-tip-mysql-equivalent-of-isnumeric):

```
... AND value REGEXP ('[0-9]')
```

... but someone's blog is never the best source. Actually that matches everything that contains a number. Better would be

```
... AND value REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$')
```

Above regex is

```
^      "From the begining of the string..."
[0-9]  "There should be a number..."
+      "actually exactly 1 or more of those numbers"
$      "and the the string should just end."
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry - should have put it above - but would you know of anyway to exclude values that contain both numbers and letters as well? Eg: RED123?

Comment: If the current answer doesn't cover that case, use this: REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$')

Comment: Ah, weird, Its picking up some HTML I have stored in the table (specifically, Google Map iframes)

Comment: @MeltingDog Sorry I just edited the comment above. Try the new one.

Comment: yep, perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which does not require the `REGEXP()` function, which may not available in all RDBMS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `contentvalues` 
WHERE (contentid = 16 OR contentid =18)
    AND concat('',value * 1) = value
```

This will work as long as the numbers in the `value` column do not appear in scientific notation, with trailing decimals, or other weird formats.  Read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql) for more information.