# SQL - select all rows from table where a column contains only digits

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all rows in which a column contains only digits.

The first idea was using `LIKE [0-9]%`, but in fact this matches any strings starting with a digit.

It seems to be a very simple task, but unfortunately I can't find solution

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: If it's MS SQL 2005 or later, I believe you will require support for regular expressions (or *regex*) to acheive your goal.  You will need to write a CLR function.  A (slightly dated) example is here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f9935e/harnessing-regular-expressions-in-sql-server-using-clr-integration/

Comment: They say mySQL 5.5 is used. But if i'm not mistaken "REGEXP" is possible in mySQL, but in my case it doesn't work

Comment: If you're using mySQL try checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

In `Sql server` use `Not Like`

```
where some_column NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

**Demo**

```
declare @str varchar(50)='asdarew345'

select 1 where @str NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f7ac/2)

For `Mysql` use [`REGEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE string_column REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```