# Exclude alphabetic characters from string on Redshift

Tags: mysql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have several two character strings that include numbers like:

01, 02, 03 etc,  However, there are others that look like this:

0P, as, JJ, F1, F2, XP, PK, TL, WQ

I am looking to exclude the ones in the second row with a query on redshift using their "not like" syntax. Tried several combinations and can't get it to work.  Ideally, I am looking for a way to exclude any two character string that includes an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a regular expresion

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable 
  WHERE columnName REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Or if you want restrict to two characters

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable 
  WHERE columnName  REGEXP '[0-9][0-9]';
```

You say want `to exclude any two character string that includes an alphabetic character.`

This bring all where both chars are number.

Comment: not working ( note that I am on Amazon Redshift). Will the syntax be different ?  my code looks like :  `where right( column_id, 2 ) REGEXP '[0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: I found another solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql

Comment: Also you have [**REGEXP_REPLACE**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)  You can replace all number for `''` and see if you get a 0 length string,,, or all alpha and see if length is the same. But I dont have access to redshift to give you the right syntaxis