# How to get max integer value of a column in java sql?

Tags: java, mysql

Basically I have a Sql Column named phone, where it contains numbers and letter.
I want to get the max integer value of my phone table, I found that it is possible using `MAX()` but for me that return max letters not the number value.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM db.stb";
```

I need the output result to be this `00010511000000000` which is the maximum value in my column

and I really appreciate if you tell me how to specify my column name in my query, something like:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM db.stb WHERE COLUMNNAME=PHONE";
```

Comment: First question here is why are you storing two different information in a single column ? That is wrong

Comment: show some sample data of that column. And add your expected output based on that.

Comment: What is the type of the column?  Is db.stb really the table name?

Comment: `DB` is the database name and `stb` is the table name

Comment: Also `Mysql` <> `SQL Server` choose the one yo are using

Comment: i updated my question, see what i exactly want above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in comments, you should not store two different information in a single column. Consider changing the table structure.

With this structure to get the result, first filter out the rows with alphabet on it. Use `REGEXP` to filter the records which has only numeric values. Then take the max value out of it.

```
SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM db.stb WHERE col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

`REGEX` concept taken from this question :  [Detect if value is number in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Comment: I just did the way you said and the result was: `john.fobmate`

Comment: @jacky Ok, Try this `SELECT PHONE FROM db.stb WHERE col1 REGEXP '[0-9]+'` and tell whether you are getting any non-numeric data in result

Comment: Ok that printed the integer value but not the max value

Comment: okay i got the point,  change the `john.fobmate` to `john.fobmate1` and you will see the result, and in your table i want the result to be `234`

Comment: @jacky Fact is I don't know anything about `REGEX` in `Mysql`. Just did a better google search ;) Start using google you can do wonders