# How do I count values in columns of a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
id | produit   | qte | amount
----------------------------
1  | iphone    |  15 |  110$
2  | tablet    |  18 |  50$
3  | laptop    |  19 |  250.99$
4  | Tide      |  21 |  10$
```

How can I count the Total amount of all this produit in this table ?

Comment: You need to use aggregate functions. You also shouldn't store those as varchar, now you've your work cut out.

Comment: Are you looking for `SUM()` ?

Comment: I m using mysql and php and i want to show the final result of total amount  in a table html

Comment: Don't store '$'.

Comment: what you should have done was store `amount` as a type that uses integers and simply tack on the `$` sign in php afterwards. If you're not too far into this, it's not too late to alter your column.

Comment: *"How can I count the Total amount of all this produit in this table ?"* - Re-reading your question, am now asking myself "which column you want to count here", the `produit` column or another, or all? This question is starting to look unclear; can you clarify your question?

Comment: i want to count the total amount $$ of this commande

Comment: please just provide expected result value - that should clarify everything, while we are still guessing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query using `SUM` and `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(amount, '$', '') AS DECIMAL) 
FROM table_name
```

> I recommend you to remove the `$` from column `amount` instead of using a query like the above one! The script / frontend working with these values should know which currency the column is using.

**How you can improve your database design / column?**

Remove all the `$` from this column using the following query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET amount = TRIM(REPLACE(amount, '$', ''))
```

Execute the [following query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065007/3840840) to get all non numeric values:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE NOT CONCAT('', amount * 1) = amount
```

If the query above don't return any rows you can `ALTER` your table to change the column type to `DECIMAL(6, 2)` or `DOUBLE` (There can be floating numbers?):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN amount DECIMAL(6, 2)
```

Comment: OMG :-) even if this will work, we can't accept that as an answer on SO :-) that is very wrong path to go

Comment: Sure that stands to work. However, the use of multiple functions could have been and should be avoided. [***This....***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545216/how-do-i-count-values-in-columns-of-a-table#comment74142868_43545216) is what they really should do or have done in the first place, before starting their project.

Comment: @Alex - you are right. I added some steps for improving the table. I saw you answer to late...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your table structure to store your `amount` as `DOUBLE` but not `VARCHAR`

```
UPDATE t SET amount = REPLACE(amount, '$','');

ALTER TABLE t MODIFY amount DOUBLE;
```

and then you can use aggregated function `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c335cc/1

Comment: Agreed, yet I've asked for clarification in comments and have yet to hear from [this one I left...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545216/how-do-i-count-values-in-columns-of-a-table#comment74143239_43545216). IMHO, the question's unclear as to *what* they want to count here, should `COUNT()` need to be used. All the more reasons why I didn't submit an answer of my own.

Comment: I guess OP meant *calculate* but not the `COUNT`  function. It is just about terms. for any DBA *count* means `COUNT()` but in English it could mean kind of *calculate* :-)

Comment: I guess: `total amount = SUM(amount)`

Comment: Yes, there could be a language barrier. OP placed a comment under their question but I don't know what they meant by that. Maybe just the `amount` column. OP: *"i want to count the total amount $$ of this commande"* @Alex

Comment: @Fred-ii- exactly I want to count just the amount column

Comment: Please use `int` or `decimal` instead of `double` for amounts. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/854080

Comment: @RachidBahman Count as in and seeing you have 4 rows, to show there are 4 rows or the total sum of and for example: `1.00$` times 4 rows being `4.00$`?

Comment: @Alex Just to let you know that I'm not planning on submitting an answer to overtake yours; just trying to help out here :-) I think y'all can take over from here; see what the OP writes in response to my above comment to them.