# Bulk Update / Replace mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am really new to mysql and might need your help. I have a a table called `localgames` and I am trying to replace some values to clean the table so here is the doubt and what I have tried and the proposed "solution":

To replace a simple entry that was easy, I used:

```
UPDATE localgames 
   SET Stock = REPLACE(Stock, '0 in stock', 'Sold out');
```

So all `0 in stock` entries in the column Stock where replaced by `Sold out`. Cool.

However now I have another entries for example `1 in stock`, `2 in stock`, `3 in stock` and more 100 of `XX in stock` and I want to replace them all for `In stock`.

Is there a way to use something like `SET Stock = REPLACE(Stock, '*.* in stock', 'In Stock');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the all mighty [`CASE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html):

```
UPDATE inventory
SET quantity = CASE WHEN quantity = '0 in stock' THEN 'Out of Stock' ELSE 'In Stock' END
```

See my SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2494c6/1

Alternatively, [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) works as well:

```
UPDATE inventory
SET quantity = IF(quantity = '0 in stock', 'Out of stock', 'In Stock')
```

SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4551a8/1

**Update: In response to your comment, another 2 ways (If you have REGEXP support)**

```
UPDATE inventory
SET quantity = CASE WHEN quantity = '0 in stock' THEN 'Out of Stock'
  WHEN quantity REGEXP '^[0-9]+ in stock$' THEN 'In Stock'
  ELSE quantity END
```

OR simply

```
UPDATE inventory
SET quantity = IF(quantity REGEXP '^[0-9]+ in stock$', 'In Stock', quantity)
```

**Update 2: If you don't have regexp support, you can still do this (Albeit in a hacky way):**

Assuming you've already converted the 0 in stock to out of stock, you can use this:

```
UPDATE inventory
SET quantity = IF(
    CONCAT('', SUBSTR(quantity, 1, 1) * 1) = SUBSTR(quantity, 1, 1),
    'In Stock',
    quantity
)
```

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql) for determining if something is a number, and I'm using `SUBSTR(quantity, 1, 1)` to determine if the first letter in the string is a number, and if so, setting it. Be aware **This will not work, if you have things like 1 in backorder**.

See the SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1774c6/1

Comment: Tanks for answer. The thing is: I have other things listed in the Stock field like Pre-Order, Backorder etc. Not only "In Stock" and "Sold out". :(  Any other clues? Cheers

Comment: @RafaelSouza Just keep using the CASE statement, to define everything.

Comment: @RafaelSouza Also, what's your DB version? Percona/Mariadb have some extra functionality that may help.

Comment: Depending on your DB version, and if you have REGEXP support (Percona/Mariadb have it, and later versions of MySQL), you can use that.

Comment: lol, which did you use, curious @RafaelSouza? This was fun times doing research.

Comment: Fantastic answer! So just to be able to complete my task, I have other text like "Pre-order - out 22 Jun 2018 (estimated date)" or "Pre-order - out 25 Jun 2018" etc and I want to transform all in "Pre-Order" only. Is there a way to do this? Thanks heaps!

Comment: mysql version 5.7

Comment: `quantity REGEXP '^Pre-order'` should match where the field starts with `Pre-order`

Comment: @FranferZ everything else worked like a charm! Since I am very new to mysql do you mind to exemplify how this quantity REGEXP '^Pre-order' works? So I need to update the field Stock to replace all "Pre-Order something" to "Pre-Order. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh sorry, just adding a last one: also I would like to replace all blanks to "Stock unk" do you think this will work?
UPDATE localgames 
   SET Stock = REPLACE(Stock, '', 'Stock unk');

Comment: `UPDATE localgames SET Stock = IF(Stock = '', 'Stock Unknown', Stock);`.

Comment: You're a genius! What about this one? "Since I am very new to mysql do you mind to exemplify how this quantity REGEXP '^Pre-order' works? So I need to update the field Stock to replace all "Pre-Order something" to "Pre-Order. Thank you so much! "

Comment: yes indeed I said last one, but this question was there before the "last one" :)

Comment: `quantity REGEXP '^Pre-order'` is simply a conditional (Will return true or false). REGEXP is regular expression, and it has a very unique but very powerful syntax for matching patterns of strings. `UPDATE localgames SET Stock = IF("The Stock starts with Preorder (This should be true or false)", "What to set it to if Stock does start with Pre-order", "What to set it to if Stock does not start with Pre-order")`. Take a look at my previous examples.

Comment: ok I got it, so do you think that this should work? I don't want to set anything "if stock do not start with Pre-order" so I did this: UPDATE localgames SET Stock = IF("^Pre-order", "Pre-order");

do you think this is the way to go? Cheers

Comment: `IF` takes 3 parameters, you can't simply omit one. (Hint: Setting `Stock` to `Stock` is essentially leaving it the same). #2: "^Pre-order" is a string, it's not a boolean. (Again, take a look at my other examples)

Comment: What about this?
UPDATE localgames
SET Stock = IF(Stock REGEXP '^Pre-order', 'Pre-order', Stock)

Comment: Yup! Also, slight formatting note (Use backticks `\`` around code, to format them nicely in comments).