# IsNumeric and Case-when to count numeric values and change how it's displayed in results

Tags: sql, case-when, isnumeric

I'm trying to pull counts from a survey customers answer over the phone.  The survey has 3 questions and the answers are sometimes numeric and sometimes words. I want to count the answers but need the any numeric values to be counted and displayed as NUMERIC_ENTRY.  I've been trying 'IsNumeric' and 'Case when' but can't the results correct.

**Sample Data:**

```
Question | Answer  
Q1       | 12  
Q1       | 456  
Q1       | 8  
Q1       | DontKnow  
Q1       | TellMeHow  
Q2       | Yes  
Q3       | No
```

**Sample Result:**

```
Question | Asnwer          | Count  
Q1       |  NUMERIC_ENTRY  | 3  
Q1       | DontKnow        | 1  
Q1       | TellMeHow       | 1  
Q2       | Yes             | 1  
Q3       | No              | 1
```

**The Example SQL:**

```
select Question, Answer, count (*) from Survey
where Client = 'ABC_Company'   
group by Question, Answer
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Before we go any further you need to decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. Then feel free to add the database specific tag for the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRY_PARSE` function provided your version is *SQL Server 2012 or above* ( *@Gordon is right using `ISNUMERIC` function might be problematic as in the below demonstration link* ):

```
select q.Question, q.AnswerCount, count(q.AnswerCount) as count
  from
(
select Question, 
       (case when TRY_PARSE(Answer as int) is not null then 'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
            else Answer end) as AnswerCount
  from Survey   
 where Client = 'ABC_Company'   
 group by Question, Answer
) as q
group by q.Question, q.AnswerCount
order by q.Question, count desc
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/XPA11201)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` and a pattern, that matches any non digit character.

```
SELECT question,
       CASE
         WHEN answer = ''
               OR answer LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
           answer
         ELSE
           'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
       END answer,
       count(*)
       FROM survey
       WHERE client = 'ABC_Company'   
       GROUP BY question,
                CASE
                  WHEN answer = ''
                        OR answer LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                    answer
                  ELSE
                    'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
                END;
```

(Assuming SQL Server because of the `isnumeric()` (which you can use too, but as it's known to produce funny results sometimes, I'd rather go for the `LIKE`).)

Another option since SQL Server 2012 is to use `try_cast()`, to check if the string can be converted into an integer.

```
SELECT question,
       CASE
         WHEN answer = ''
               OR try_cast(answer AS integer) IS NULL
           answer
         ELSE
           'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
       END answer,
       count(*)
       FROM survey
       WHERE client = 'ABC_Company'   
       GROUP BY question,
                CASE
                  WHEN answer = ''
                        OR try_cast(answer AS integer) IS NULL
                    answer
                  ELSE
                    'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
                END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL:** Taking idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065007/2469308, you can check if a string is numeric or not, using [If()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) function.

Try the following query:

```
select Question, 
       IF(CONCAT('',Answer * 1) = Answer, 'NUMERIC_ENTRY', Answer) AS Ans, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM Survey
where Client = 'ABC_Company'   
GROUP BY Question, Ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `isnumeric()`.  You'll be surprised at some of the things considered numeric (`'$'`, `','`, and `'3e2'` for instance).

So, `like` is your friend in this case.  By `numeric`, I assume you mean all digits.  Because you want to aggregate by the results, you need to refer to the column twice.  So, I'm going to suggest `apply`:

```
select s.question, v.answer_group, count(*)
from survey s cross apply
     (values (case when s.answer like '%[^0-9]%' then s.answer  -- has non-digit
                   else 'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
              end)
     ) v(answer_group)
group by s.question, v.answer_group
order by s.question, count(*) desc, v.answer_group;
```

Note that this treats the empty string as numeric.  This is easily adjusted; your question is not clear about what to do in that case.  I might suggest:

```
     (values (case when ltrim(rtrim(s.answer)) = '' or s.answer is null then 'BLANK_ENTRY'
                   when s.answer like '%[^0-9]%' then s.answer  -- has non-digit
                   else 'NUMERIC_ENTRY'
              end)
     ) v(answer_group)
```

Comment: I am really surprised that isnumeric() considers '$' as numeric, 
I use isnumeric() often and never notice any strange behavior, it always acted as intended.

Comment: @Markov . . . I'll let you run the examples.