# How to filter only integer number with a length in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a data which contain string output. I want to select the data with only numeric and its length between 10 or 11. How to achieve that in MYSQL?

My Data :

```
0123458921
12344asd12341
012-38jh213a
12398798797
```

Expected Output :

```
0123458921
12398798797
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' and length(column_name) in (10,11)
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=44c40d4593a0bce296231eab20efd196)

Answer (score 2):

We can combine both where clause to one to improve performance

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[0-9]{10,11}$'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc044e/2