# Having trouble using ISNUMERIC function in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE people
SET name ='numeric'
WHERE ISNUMERIC (name) =1;
```

Trying to set all names in name column which are numeric values to 'numeric'.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: It is saying function socialdb.ISNUMERIC does not exist.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` isn't a [tag:mysql] built-in function. Is it possible you're copying some code from [tag:sql-server]? Even if so, it's an almost pointless function there too, answering a question nobody wants to ask.

Comment: Is there any alternative to check if any numerics are present in column?

Comment: ISNUMERIC doesn't exist in MySQL.  You would have to create it.  A simple Google search turned up this: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,599995,599995

Comment: [Detect if value is numeric in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC()` is a function in SQL Server.  I don't even recommend using the function in that database -- the `TRY_CAST()` and `TRY_CONVERT()` are more accurate.

In MySQL, you can use regular expressions.  It is unclear what you mean by "isnumeric" in this context, but:

```
UPDATE people
    SET name = 'numeric'
    WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$';
```

This gets any things with a string of digits, at most one decimal point, and at least one digit before the decimal point.  It is easy to modify for negative numbers and exponential notation if that is really what you intend.

If by "numeric" you just mean a string of digits, then:

```
UPDATE people
    SET name = 'numeric'
    WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using the HAVING clause, here. The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

```
UPDATE people
SET name ='numeric'
HAVING ISNUMERIC (name) =1;
```