# Can you do a where find with a regular expression in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find objects that begin with a number.

Syntactically this is off. But I would like to do something *like* this :

```
Object.where([name LIKE ?', /[1-9]/])
```

If that isn't possible, how do you suppose the best way to find all objects that start with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select values that begin with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511945/select-values-that-begin-with-a-number)

```
Object.where(['name REGEXP ?', '^[0-9]'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use rlike / regexp i would think. Though it's not portable across to other databases.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

```
Object.where(['name rlike ?', '^[\d]'])
```

Comment: Hmm so that didn't work, but this did `where(['name rlike ?', '^[1-9]'])`