# Check number of one column from other column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns, say `dialer_code` and `country_code`. I need to check whether the `dialer_code` matches with the `country_code` or not.

Example: `dialer_code = 1234567890`, so it will check whether `1234567890` in `country_code` matches any `country_code` entry. If not then it will remove the last digit (turning the value into `123456789`) and check again. This repeats until only the first 2 digit are left.

```
dialer_code    country_code     country_name
190095               91         India
190098               44         UK
4456                 20         Egypt
445678               1900       US
```

In the above example, `190095` will be checked in `country_code`, but we don't have anything matching with it so now it will check for `country_code` `19009`, but we don't have anything matching it either, until we get to `1900`. Now it's matching with US. So US has some call rate defined per second so it will return that value.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sample data: dialer_code = 1900590. So, it will check 1900590 in the country_code column and 1900590 does not belong to any country code or any regions so it will check for 190059 in country_code till it will not find any matching column else it will take first 2 digits and we have country whose country code is 19

Comment: first, check for the length of the codes before the actual value. will it simplify the logic?

Comment: that we can use while initializing the value of the variables that we will assign

Comment: [Edit] your question with the sample data, @Akshay , and include multiple examples along with the expected results.

Comment: I mean, if you know the first 2 digits are country code. you can use regex logic. for more info check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511945/select-values-that-begin-with-a-number)

Comment: Apart from that SQL Server does *not* support Regex, @gowridev , just simple pattern matching.

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dilaer_code contains country_code, you could use SUBSTRING, like this:

```
SUBSTRING(dialer_code, CHARINDEX(country_code, dialer_code), 100)
```